# IMMUTABLE PATTERN in real life applications

Tags: design-patterns

I understand the concept of the immutable pattern , where this pattern is used when we need to create an immutable object ( an object where its states never change). However , i need to know real life applications where this pattern is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

one usage of immutable pattern is configuration that you didn't  want to changed unexpectedly.

another usage is for Data Transfer Object(DTO) that you want just transfer data.

[From CodeProject :](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043301/Immutable-objects-in-Csharp)

**Master data**: One of the biggest uses of immutable objects is to load master data. Master data like country, currency, region, etc. rarely change. So we would like to load master data once in the memory and then we do not want it to be modified.

**Configuration data**: All application needs configuration data. In the Microsoft world, we normally store these configuration data into Web.config or App.config file. Such kind of data is represented by objects and these data once loaded in the application memory will not change. It's again a good practice to make these kind of configuration data objects as immutable.

**Singleton objects**: In applications, we normally create singleton objects for shared static data. So if the shared data is not changing, it’s an awesome candidate for immutable objects. In case you are new to Singleton pattern, please refer to this article Singleton Pattern in C#.